# Double pointers when working with linked data structures in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I am new to C, practicing implementations of some common data structures. Can you explain why double pointers are preferred when doing list operations (e.g. `push_front`), as opposed to having an `SList` wrapper that contains a reference to `head`, as well as the `size` of the list, i.e. the Java way shown below.

```
typedef
struct SListNode
{
    int value;
    struct SListNode* next;
} SListNode;

typedef
struct SList
{
    /* Private members */
    int size;
    SListNode* head;
} SList;

/* API */
typedef
struct SListInterface
{   
    int (*get_size)(SList*);
    bool (*empty)(SList*);
    SListNode* (*push_front)(SList*);
} SListInterface;

/* API Implementation */
int 
get_size(SList* list)
{
    return list->size;
}

bool
empty(SList* list)
{
    return list->head == NULL;
}

SListNode*
push_front(int value, SList* list)
{
    SListNode* node = (SListNode*) malloc(sizeof(SListNode));
    node->value = value;
    node->next = list->head;
    list->head = node;
    list->size++;
}

SList* 
List(void)
{
    SList* list = (SList*) malloc(sizeof(SList));
    list->size = 0;
    list->head = NULL;

    return list;
}

SListInterface*
Interface(void)
{
    SListInterface* interface = (SListInterface*) malloc(sizeof(SListInterface));
    interface->get_size = get_size;
    interface->is_empty = is_empty;

    return interface;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any double pointers in your code. Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: @Kevin In C implementations of linked lists I often see the `push_front` function implemented with double pointers. The code I show uses a wrapper (SList) to avoid explicit double pointers. My question is why the first method seems to be the preferred one.

Comment: "Double" - you mean pointer to next and prev items? or what?

Comment: @YurySchkatula No, I mean pointers to pointers.

Comment: You mean where they pass something in as a pointer so they can update it rather than use the return value?

Comment: Because they make the code simpler, and avoid the head-node boilerplate. Note: there is an '*' missing here: `SListNode* (*push_front)(SList);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a matter of "how are we designing our solution" and "how does we want others to access the libraries".

This specific problem could be considered as an "Abstraction" problem. Generally, abstraction is considered in OOPS concepts, but it is also part of Procedural programming like C. In C language, abstraction can be obtained to some level using `static` keyword.

Here, there is no right or wrong. We could provide a wrapper so that it is more abstract to access the list and only data is to be considered, but it will also add the complexity of maintaining the wrappers. Also, as C does not support generics, so you will need different wrapper/structures for different data types, OR, you will need to make the data storage as a void* and keep a type for the list.

So, adding a wrapper makes the list usage simple for its users, but it would be complex and error-prone to maintain it at developers level.